# Why would importing pandas use up almost all my ram?

Tags: python, pandas, ram, conda

I'm fairly new to python but I'm pretty sure I didn't get this behaviour before.

A couple of days back I've noticed that if I open a new python console and simply do:

import pandas as pd

Then python.exe ram usage grows steadily in about 5 seconds to reach about 96% utilisation (ie about 15.5G of my 16G total ram).

That's not normal, right?

I'm using anaconda3 python 3.5 on windows 10....I've updated my conda and pandas but to no avail...

Cheers

Comment: No, I've never noticed this.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback...I'm embarking on a rebuild of my conda environment...hope it will solve it!

Comment: well, just make a new conda environment, with only pandas, and try and see if you can replicate the behavior. Maybe use a different interpreter: `conda create -n test_pandas python=3.6 pandas`

Comment: A brand new environment works just fine! Don't know what happened...but anyway that's the solution so let's go! Cheers buddy.

Comment: That is weird, though. Maybe keep the old environment around and file a bug report?

Comment: Found out this was due to a package called Bottleneck which is a dependency when installing Quantopian's Empyrical package. Will raise a ticket to them when I get a minute!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so starting from a brand new environment with latest python 3.5.4 and latest panda seems to cut it....so I think I'll close this wonderful thread for now and re-open if after reinstalling all other needed libs I end up with the same problem.